# how to do hoverintent without jquery?

Tags: javascript

I don't want to include jquery in all my pages, but I'm adding a global 'popdown' menu on hover of a section, but I don't want it immediate as it's annoying when just moving the mouse around. Usually I would do this with jquery and hoverintent, but not this time.

I guess I could set a timeout on `onmouseover` for the area, but not sure if it's just that simple (like, wouldn't it fire like thousands of times while the mouse moves?)

Current code is like this...

```
<div onMouseOver="showCart();">Hover here!</div>
```

so would changing that to this work?:

```
<div onMouseOver="setTimeout(showCart, 50);">Hover here!</div>
```

Comment: a hint: you'll have to clear that timeout if the mouse is not still over the `div`.

Comment: well I'm always worried about things working in one browser and not another so maybe others know better

Comment: I hear that... [Here is Ben Alman's plugin called doTimeout.](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/hoverintent/) It uses jQuery, so I'm not telling you to use this plugin, but the code would likely be a great resource for creating your own, vanilla js solution. I'm referring you to this code over hoverintent's because I seem to remember hoverintent doing more than just setting a timeout (like actually checking if the mouse has stopped as opposed to moving over a target).

Comment: @Ibstr You could even post this as an answer I think. There is no other reasonable answer to this question other than reading the source code of projects that do exactly this. (also I don't understand why would not one use jQuery or any other library for this)

Comment: I'm just surprised there is no javascript-only 'hoverintent' type of thing out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a really simplistic Vanilla DOM approach. This expects an element with an id `target` (for the menu item) and an element with an id 'dropdown'.

Note that this uses global old-style 'on' handlers, which is probably not a best practice (you should be using `addEventListener`), however, i think this makes the code a little more readable :)

I've also setup a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nt8Pq/1)

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
var curEl;

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    curEl = e.target || e.srcElement;
}

target.onmouseover = function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (curEl === target || curEl === dropdown) {
            dropdown.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            dropdown.style.display = "none";
        }
    }, 300);
}

target.onmouseout = dropdown.onmouseout = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (curEl !== target && curEl !== dropdown) {
            dropdown.style.display = "none";
        }
    }, 300);
}
```

Comment: looks interesting, but tried the jsFiddle in IE and doesn't seem to be working (FF is ok)

Comment: I've updated the example to make it work on IE. The new jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nt8Pq/1/

Comment: it works in IE now thanks. Ready to put this in my javascript library but I noticed something that may have to do with it being in jsFiddle... If you run the mouse quickly over it from above to below it works ok, but if you run the mouse quickly from below to above (ending in the CSS area) it still pops down

Comment: It looks like thats because the target is at the edge of the page and when your mouse leaves the page, it thinks its position is still at the edge (still on the target). If you add some margin to the target, the problem goes away. I'm not sure how to fix it otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

well, my initial attempt failed miserably, but then made it work like so...

```
<div onmouseover="window.mycarthoverin = 1; setTimeout(showCart, 100);" onmouseout="window.mycarthoverin = 0;">Hover here!</div>
```

And then inside `showCart`...

```
if (window.mycarthoverin == 1) {
  ...
}
```

Anybody see a problem with this approach I may not be aware of?

Comment: I know I'm late... but this should work nicely. But it's not hoverintent... hoverintent throws a custom event when it determines a user "intended" to hover over something. It does that when the [mouse movement slows down a certain amount](https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent/blob/master/jquery.hoverIntent.js#L67).